# Auto change font color of words in a text after x seconds

Tags: javascript, css, animation, text, colors

I need help with the following - I have a range of words, i.e.:
term1 term2 term3 term4
I want to start all terms with the same color - then, after i.e. 3 seconds, term1 should turn green, then after another 3 seconds, term2 should turn green (but term1 should go back to basic color) - when you're at the end of term4, animation should start from the beginning (loop).
I've been fiddling around with CSS animation, but it didn't turn out as expected - can anyone help? If it can't be done purely in CSS, maybe with Javascript?

Thanks for every input!

Comment: Is this a set number of terms or is it dynamic? Is it text all together or spread out in other text?

Comment: Do you want the text to be inside one element or more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have set timeout for 1 second

```js
var terms = ["term1", "term2", "term3"];
var counter = 0;
setTimeout(function(){ highlight(terms[counter]); }, 1000);
function highlight(text) {
  counter++;
  if(counter == 3)
      counter = 0;
  var element = document.getElementById("data")
  var data =  new String(element.innerText);
  element.innerHTML = data.replaceAll(text, '<mark class=red>' + text + '</mark>');
  setTimeout(function(){ highlight(terms[counter]); }, 1000);
}
```

```css
mark.red {
    color:#ff0000;
    background: none;
   }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
   
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="data">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply term1 dummy text of term2 the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the term2 industry's term2 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,  term1 when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, term3 but term1  also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining term3essentially unchanged. term2 It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of term3 Letraset term1  sheets containing term3 Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
function changeColor() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const elems = container.querySelectorAll('span');
    const elemsCount = elems.length;
    let i = 0;
    let prevElem = elems[elemsCount - 1];
    setInterval(() => {
        const currElem = elems[i % elemsCount];
        currElem.style.color = 'rgb(0,255,0)';
        prevElem.style.color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        prevElem = currElem;
        i++;
    }, 3000); // change this value to speed up/slow down the cicle
}

changeColor();
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!! Thanks a LOT! Will try it out with my individual set but looks great - Grazie

Comment: One little thing - my editor says there is a synthax error with 
let i = 0;
tried it in MS Edge and it's not starting the animation...

Comment: Also, how would it have to be modified if I want to start with green number right away, then after 3 secs, "2" turns green and "1" goes back to black and so on as above?

Comment: @user141856 This would only if all the text data is into span tag. May be you want to look at the more general solution that I posted below. Not that this isn't a solution

Comment: Bharat, I also tried with your solution and it's also working well, thank you - one question - how do I add line breaks within the data div? <br/> don't work....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an elementary question, I will use jQuery. In fact, you are free to use any other frontend framework if you wish to
HTML:

```
<div id="banner-message">
   <ul>
   <li>term 1</li>
      <li>term 2</li>
         <li>term 3</li>
            <li>term 4</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var terms = jQuery("ul li");
  var i=0;
    setInterval(changeColor, 1000);
  function changeColor() {
    jQuery(terms[i]).siblings().removeClass('red');
    jQuery(terms[i]).addClass('red');
    i+=1;
    if (i==terms.length) i==0;
  }
})
```

CSS:

```
.red {
  color:red;
}
```

Watch it live here: